# Как подключить импорты из _Imports.razor в razor файле, который находится в отдельной от Pages папке?

Tags: c#, razor

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему компонент razor, который находится в отдельной от папки Pages, не видит импорты и просит явно указать их или использовать

```
@using UseCases.UseCasesInterfaces
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я удалил razor файл, создал заново точь-в-точь такой же и все импорты успешно нашло ¯_(ツ)_/¯